# "stale association proxy, parent object has gone out of scope" with Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I've actually never encountered this error before:

`sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: stale association proxy, parent object has gone out of scope`

After doing some research, it looks like its because the parent object is being garbage collected while the association proxy is working. Fantastic.

However, I'm not sure *where* it's happening.

Relevant code:

```
# models.py

class Artist(db.Model):
    # ...
    tags = association_proxy('_tags', 'tag', 
        creator=lambda t: ArtistTag(tag=t))
    # ...

class Tag(db.Model):
    # ...
    artist = association_proxy('_artists', 'artist', 
        creator=lambda a: ArtistTag(artist=a))
    # ...

class ArtistTag(db.Model):
    # ...
    artist_id = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('artists.id'))
    artist = db.relationship('Artist', backref='_tags')
    tag_id = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('tags.id'))
    tag = db.relationship('Tag', backref='_artists')

# api/tag.py
from flask.ext.restful import Resource
from ..
class ListArtistTag(Resource):
    def get(self, id):
        # much safer in actual app
        return TagSchema(many=True)
               .dump(Artist.query.get(id).tags)
               .data
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I know it's an old question, but I haven't found a clear solution to a similar problem anywhere on the web, so I've decided to reply here.

The key here is to assign the object that holds the association proxy to a variable before performing any further operations on them. Association proxies aren't regular object properties which would force the GC to hold the reference to the parent object. Actually, the call in form of:

```
tags = association_proxy('_tags', 'tag', creator=lambda t: ArtistTag(tag=t))
```

will result in creation of a new `AssociationProxy` class object, with a weak reference to the target's collection. In low memory conditions, GC may try to collect  `Artist.query.get(id)` result, leaving just the result's `tags` collection (being a `AssociationProxy` class object), but it's required that the object having a association proxy to be present, due to SQLAlchemy's implementation (lazy loading mechanism precisely, I believe).

To fix this situation, we need to make sure that the `Artist` object returned from `Artist.query.get(id)` call is assigned to a variable, so that the reference count to that object is explicitly of non-zero value. So this:

```
class ListArtistTag(Resource):
    def get(self, id):
        # much safer in actual app
        return TagSchema(many=True)
               .dump(Artist.query.get(id).tags)
               .data
```

becomes this:

```
class ListArtistTag(Resource):
    def get(self, id):
        artist = Artist.query.get(id)
        return TagSchema(many=True)
               .dump(artist.tags)
               .data
```

And it will work as expected. Simple, right?

Comment: Good find. In CPython you don't even need low mem conditions, as the temporary query result's refcount goes to 0 and it will be collected immediately after accessing. The identity map of SQLA is also weak, so it'll not keep the instance alive either.

Comment: I'll have to revisit the project this came from, but everything you've said makes sense.

Comment: Was having the same issue and this solved it. In my case I was directly assigning the attribute value to a variable, which was used elsewhere. I had to copy the content (`list(*self.associated_proxy_list)`)