# sqlalchemy InvalidRequestError: stale association proxy, parent object has gone out of scope

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I'm pretty new to sqlalchemy.  I've searched online and haven't been able to find anything helpful in the forums or in the sqlalchemy documentation.

I'm on:
Python 3.4
sqlalchemy 1.0.11

Here are the relevant code snippets:

models.py

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, Date, Numeric, Boolean
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy

Base = declarative_base()

emp_exemptions_table = Table('emp_exemptions', Base.metadata,
    Column('employee_id',
           Integer,
           ForeignKey('employee.id'),
           primary_key=True),
    Column('exemptReasons_id',
           Integer,
           ForeignKey('exemptReasons.id'),
           primary_key=True)
)

current_exemptions_table = Table('current_exemptions', Base.metadata,
    Column('exemption_id',
           Integer,
           ForeignKey('exemption.id'),
           primary_key=True),
    Column('exemptReasons_id',
           Integer,
           ForeignKey('exemptReasons.id'),
           primary_key=True)
)


class ExemptReasons(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'exemptReasons'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    text = Column('exemptReasons',
                  String(30),
                  nullable=True)

    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

class Employee(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'employee'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    eid = Column(String(8), nullable=False)
    hours = Column(Numeric(), nullable=False)
    exempt = Column(Boolean(), nullable=False)
    exempt_reasons = relationship(ExemptReasons,
                                  secondary=lambda: emp_exemptions_table)
    as_of_date = Column(Date())

    # proxy the 'exempt_reason' attribute from the 'exempt_reasons' relationship
    reasons = association_proxy('exempt_reasons', 'text')


class CurrentExemption(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'exemption'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    eid = Column(String(8), nullable=False)
    effective_date = Column(Date())
    exempt = Column(Boolean(), nullable=False)
    exempt_reasons = relationship(ExemptReasons,
                                  secondary=lambda: current_exemptions_table)
    # proxy the 'exempt_reason' attribute from the 'exempt_reasons' relationship
    reasons = association_proxy('exempt_reasons', 'text')

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///sqldb_example.db')

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

relevant functions

```
def determine_eligibility_changes(self, elig):

    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///sqldb_example.db')
    Base.metadata.bind = engine
    DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = DBSession()

    student_reason = session.query(ExemptReasons).filter_by(text='Student Rule 3121(b)(10)').first()

    new_exemptions = []

    for e in elig:
        current_elig = session.query(Employee).filter_by(eid=e['eid']).first()  #todo: add time filter

        if current_elig.reasons:
            new_elig_reasons = current_elig.reasons
        else:
            new_elig_reasons = []

        if e['eligible']:

            if current_elig.exempt:
                if not (student_reason.text in current_elig.reasons):
                    new_elig_reasons.append(student_reason.text)
            else:
                new_elig_reasons.append(student_reason.text)
        else:  # not eligible now

            if current_elig.exempt:
                if student_reason.text in current_elig.reasons:
                    new_elig_reasons.remove(student_reason.text)
        e['exempt_reasons'] = new_elig_reasons

        new_exemptions.append(e)

    session.close()
    return new_exemptions


def store_current_eligibility(self, lines):
    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///sqldb_example.db')
    Base.metadata.bind = engine
    DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = DBSession()
    for x in lines:
        new_eligibility = CurrentExemption(eid=x['eid'],
                                           effective_date=datetime.today(),  
                                           exempt=x['eligible'],
                                           reasons=x['exempt_reasons'],
                                           )

        session.add(new_eligibility)
    session.commit()
```

traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "start_calculator.py", line 5, in <module>
    app.run()
  File "/Users/hayne/bitbucket/APP005/app005/main_calculator.py", line 42, in run
    EligibilityCalculator.store_current_eligibility(self, new_list)
  File "/Users/hayne/bitbucket/APP005/app005/calculator/eligibility.py", line 134, in store_current_eligibility
    reasons=x['exempt_reasons'],
  File "<string>", line 4, in __init__
  File "/Users/hayne/.virtualenvs/APP005/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state.py", line 306, in _initialize_instance
    manager.dispatch.init_failure(self, args, kwargs)
  File "/Users/hayne/.virtualenvs/APP005/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 60, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "/Users/hayne/.virtualenvs/APP005/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 183, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/hayne/.virtualenvs/APP005/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state.py", line 303, in _initialize_instance
    return manager.original_init(*mixed[1:], **kwargs)
  File "/Users/hayne/.virtualenvs/APP005/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/base.py", line 649, in _declarative_constructor
    setattr(self, k, kwargs[k])
  File "/Users/hayne/.virtualenvs/APP005/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/associationproxy.py", line 283, in __set__
    self._set(proxy, values)
  File "/Users/hayne/.virtualenvs/APP005/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/associationproxy.py", line 352, in _set
    proxy.extend(values)
  File "/Users/hayne/.virtualenvs/APP005/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/associationproxy.py", line 617, in extend
    for v in values:
  File "/Users/hayne/.virtualenvs/APP005/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/associationproxy.py", line 604, in __iter__
    for member in self.col:
  File "/Users/hayne/.virtualenvs/APP005/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/associationproxy.py", line 509, in <lambda>
    col = property(lambda self: self.lazy_collection())
  File "/Users/hayne/.virtualenvs/APP005/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/associationproxy.py", line 465, in __call__
    "stale association proxy, parent object has gone out of "
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: stale association proxy, parent object has gone out of scope
```

So when I run this, it's hitting the error when I try to populate the reasons m2m key.  It does get past the commit for the first record, and it bombs on the second record.  The first record has one value in the list but the second record has no values.  I've stored empty lists into the relationship field elsewhere in my code so I don't think that's the issue.  Is the issue how I remove the elements from my list in determine_eligibility_changes?  Can I not simply remove it from the list?  Does something else/more need to be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["stale association proxy, parent object has gone out of scope" with Flask-SQLAlchemy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30044069/stale-association-proxy-parent-object-has-gone-out-of-scope-with-flask-sqlalc)